# How do I open a dialog and retrieve strings from it, in Qt4?

Tags: c++, qt4

This is the main window so far and the second window is a dialog window. How do I get the text from a textbox on window2 when it closes?
Thanks.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "window2.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->actionExit, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(closeProgram()));
    connect(ui->openWindowBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(openSecondWindow()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::openSecondWindow()
{
    Window2 w2;
    w2.exec();
}

void MainWindow::closeProgram()
{
    close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Found Solution

All I had to do is create a getString() function in the Window2 class to retreive the text from ui->...

```
QString Window2::getString()
{
    return ui->textEdit->text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your .ui file in designer (or the resulting generated file from the uic), and access the [`QLineEdit`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qlineedit.html) object by name (the same way you connect that signal). You can retrieve the text with the lineEdit::text() accessor.

Comment: I have a line edit called textEdit on the second window but the object w2.textEdit doesn't exists. 'class Window2' has no member named 'textEdit'